# C++ std::sort implementation

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, quicksort

I am wondering as to the implementation of `std::sort` in `c++11`. I have an `MPI`-managed parallel code, where each rank reads data from a file into a vector `A` that needs to be sorted. Each rank does calls `std::sort` to do this.

When I run this with ~100 ranks, there is sometimes one rank which hangs at this call to `std::sort`. Eventually, I realized, it's not hanging, the sort just takes very long. That is, one rank will take ~200 times longer to sort than all of the others.

At first I suspected it was a load-balancing issue. Nope, I've checked thoroughly that the size of `A` per rank is as balanced as possible.

I've concluded that it may just simply be that one rank has an initial condition of `A` such that something like the [worst-case performance of quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis) is realized (or at least a non-ideal-case).

Why do I think this?

- If I change the `MPI` configuration (thereby perturbing the content of `A` per rank, since it comes from a file read), the issue disappears, or it can move to other ranks.
- If I change `std::sort` to `std::stable_sort` (no longer using the quicksort algorithm), then all is fine.

However, it seems that it would be most sensible to implement a quicksort by choosing a *random* pivot point on each iteration. If that were the case with `std::sort`, then it would be overwhelmingly unlikely to choose a worst-case value randomly from `A` on many iterations (which would be required to result in a 200x performance hit).

Thus, my observations suggest that `std::sort` implements a *fixed* quicksort pivot value (e.g. always choose the first value in the array, or something like that). This is the only way that the behavior I'm seeing would be likely, and also give consistent results when re-running on the same `MPI` configuration (which it does).

Am I correct in that conclusion? I did manage to find the `std` source, but the `sort` function is totally unreadable, and makes a plethora of calls to various helper functions, and I'd rather avoid a rabbit hole. Aside from that, I'm running on an HPC system, and it's not even clear to me how to be sure what exactly `mpicxx` is linking to. I can't find any documentation which describe the algorithm implementation

Comment: As far as I know, the standard does not require any specific sorting algorithm. Only that complexity be `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Most implementations of `std::sort` use introsort. I believe that the standard may even prohibit straight quicksort with time complexity requirements.

Comment: @Justin Hmm, introsort should behave much better, so that would suggest that my suspicions are wrong...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That is true of quicksort on average. Jarod's answer suggests that that should prevent it from being used in the case that I compile with `c++11`, though

Comment: @Anonymous: That might depend. It's always possible that you're using an implementation that doesn't conform in this respect. For example, the compiler has been updated to handle C++11 code, but the library (for whatever reason) doesn't quite match, and continues to implement std::sort in a way that's no longer conforming.

Comment: you can check your assumption by swapping the first element with a random position and compare the runtimes again

Comment: @user463035818 Good call, I've had the bad rank dump out the data and I'm going to play with it now. Will edit shortly

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort` is implementation specific.

And since C++11, regular quicksort is no longer a valid implementation as required complexity move from `O(N log N)` on **average** to `O(N log N)`.

Comment: Ah, thanks a bunch. So I am wrong in my suspicions? I am compiling with `--std=c++11`